# Что лучше: много типов исключений или много кодов ошибок?

Tags: исключения

Для программного распознавания различных ошибок в класс приходится вводить много констант с кодами ошибок. Это несколько утяжеляет код и читаемость класса, поэтому возник вопрос: целесообразно ли на каждую ошибку создавать исключение, которое, в случае надобности, будет обработано по типу, а не по коду? Считается ли такой подход хорошей практикой, не труден ли в обслуживании? Сейчас ошибок всего 13 в рамках одного класса. В среднем в проекте будет до 30 на класс, в некоторых не будет вообще.

Answer (score 0):

Разный тип ошибок целесообразно, если в данном участке кода будет обрабатываться только свои логические (без нехватки памяти или что-то ещё). Тогда создаёте свой тип ошибки , только который вы и будете обрабатывать. Если вы будете во всех местах анализировать любую ошибку, тогда проще сделать один тип с подробным описанием места в программе.

```
class Exc {
    public  :
       wchar_t const * place { nullptr } ;
       explicit  Exc  ( wchar_t const * ) ;
} ;
    ...
    throw Exc{L"объект метод условие проблема"};
    ...
    catch(Exc e){...}
    нехватка памяти это не моя проблема идите выше 
    ...
 main(){
    catch(std::bad_alloc e){...}}
```

То-есть весь ваш код по-сути это ваша проблема, я бы сделал один класс ошибки типа **ExcAlex**. Обрабатывать свои ошибки проверяя коды никто не делает, влом. Если-что можно программно разделить код:

```
if(e.place == globalvarexcPlaceMethod12345)
```

Comment: Именно свои, логические. Но они будут обрабатываться по-разному: где-то нужно только вывести сообщение, где-то только записать лог, где-то все вместе а где-то выбросить ошибку и прекратить вывод всего остального. Посмотрев схожие вопросы на англоязычном SO, пришел к выводу, что стоит попробовать сделать свой тип на каждую ошибку.